# DNN Module Templates giving error "The type or namespace name 'DotNetNuke' could not be found"

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-9

I'm using [Christoc's Module templates](http://www.christoc.com/Products/DNN-Development-Templates) for .Net. Right out of the box I'm getting the error

```
The type or namespace name 'DotNetNuke' could not be found
```

when trying to build the project in Visual Studio 2015.

I do have the **DotNetNuke** library in my references

I've tried adding different versions of this library, but no luck yet.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

PS: I currently have DNN v9.0 installed in my computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 hours I found the solution.

I need my project to *target framework to **4.5** instead of **4.5.1**.*

I got this solution from [here](http://christoc1.rssing.com/chan-11268055/latest.php).
I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I heard there were some issues with 4.5.1 and it all depends on the .NET version you have installed on your computer.  Obviously you have 4.5.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017, in my project I change target framework from 4.5 to 4.5.1. It does not work for me also. Any solution how to fix it?